# How to create a common property in swift4

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I need a common property in my project so that I can use or share it thought out the application.
I have tried many solutions but didn't work.
I think it would make many things simple and reusable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Extension 
as documented in

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH32-ID383

you can change previously defined classes properties

example

```
extension UIColor {

    class var customGreen: UIColor {
        let darkGreen = 0x008110
        return UIColor.rgb(fromHex: darkGreen)
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of the iOS Design pattern **"Singleton"**.

Its uses only one reference for a class and the same property will get reflected where ever you are using it throughout the app.

Reference : https://thatthinginswift.com/singletons/

Comment: Avoid singletons whenever possible. 
Here's a video tutorial that illustrates the issues with singletons - and how to solve them: https://youtu.be/Uf0s3LTaj3k

Btw, the Singleton is *not* an iOS design pattern. It's one of the software design patterns that were made a standard a couple of decades ago by the Gang of Four. Even the authors considered the Singleton an evil thing. We now have better solutions for this problem, like e.g. dependency injection.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a lightweight "namespace" by declaring a public `struct` or `enum`. Then, simply add your `static` vars and you can safely share it. 
As an added benefit, you get thread-safety for free. (Static stored property initializers are thread-safe.)

```
public enum SharedConstants {
    public static var id = "MyID"
    public static var hashCode = 12345678
}
```

By the way, *extensions* are great if you want to enhance an existing type. Type extensions let you add new functionality to a type without modifying its original code.
Yet, if all you need is a common shared property, extensions may not be the best choice.